# Neo4j: Couldn't load the external resource in centos 7

Tags: csv, neo4j, centos7

I create CSV file by a software dynamically in another centos 7 server and send it to Neo4j server by Samba in home/t/Desktop/temp directory and need to load them into Neo4j.
 But Neo4j could not load the file and i get this error:

java.sql.SQLException: Some errors occurred :
[Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed]:Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/home/t/Desktop/temp/5d8db3a4-83d3-4850-b134-7e3d24855b88.csv

I comment the import line at neo4j config file and add below line to it too.

## dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

The permission for the temp directory is nobody:nobody and 0777.

But still error!!!

I think Neo4j has some issues with Selinux and other security things in Centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new top level directory (under /) e.g. named test and set the permissions appropriately:

sudo mkdir /test
sudo chmod 777 /test

by making it a top level directory you don't have to worry about permissions of intermediate directories...

answer link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127298